# Auto Unzip Files?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I download a mincraft resource pack three things show up, assets, pack.mcmeta, and pack.png. should this be a zipped file? I use an ACER laptop with windows 7. If it does auto unzip, please tell me how to turn that feature off.

Comment: It should work so long as all the files are placed in a sub folder. the second part of your question probably wont be answer here as it's not a gaming related question, it relates to computer features

Answer (score 1):

The short and simple answer is yes. Resource packs should stay zipped.

Basically what happens is Minecraft accesses the zip file at boot time or when you load a new pack. When the pack is opened it reads the pack.mcmeta file. This tells the game what the file structure of the texture pack folder is and how it needs to navigate it in order to find the textures it needs to load.

The pack.png file is simply a place holder icon to identify the resource pack by when you are in the texture pack selector.

Lastly the assets folder is just that... its the assets for the game. In the case texture files. But assets can also be sounds or language files. That is why the name changed from texture packs to RESOURCE packs as they can contain more than just textures.

I hope this answers your question.

**EDIT**

If you are not sure how to use resource packs it's quite easy. Run the game and go to `Options`, click on Resourcepacks. If you need to add new resourcepacks click the button at the bottom that says `Open resourcepack folder` and it will pop open an explorer window. Just drop the ZIP FILE in there and close it. The pack should show up in the game window just click it to select it and you're all set. On a side note depending on what pack you have and other factors the game made lag while it loads the new pack once you hit the `Done` button.

Answer (score 0):

Your computer un-zipped your file automatically for you. A downloaded resource folder usually contains the three files mentioned by you (`assets`,`pack.mcmeta`,`pack.png`), zipped. For the second question, you may want to go to other SE sites related to computer, as this is not a question related to gaming.

P.S. Welcome to Arqade!

[ADD]I recommend [Super User](http://superuser.com), it is about computers. Go have a check!